# What is the simplest way to solve determinant of a $n \times n$ matrix by upper and lower triangular matrices?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I know the basic rules to solve for the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix using upper and lower triangular matrices, but what is the simplest way?

Comment: @robert-lewis thanks for editing. sorry for my bad english ability.

Comment: What do you mean by "simplest"?  Easiest to do with a pencil and paper, or easiest to do with a computer?  Or perhaps the fastest to do with a computer?

Comment: Hey, really glad to help out.  Don't worry about your English, just keep writing it!  Cheers!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i mean the easiest and fastest solution for this issue. i know the main solution but i search for a better method.

Comment: Easiest and fastest *to be done by pencil and paper or by computer programming*?

Comment: @RobertLewis thanks man

Comment: @Omnomnomnom my priority is pencil and paper and if be it possible a step by step guide. solving it by computer is not my purpose

Comment: @RezaOnline are you aware of how to compute [determinants by Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computing_determinants)?  You could just row-reduce until you have an upper-triangular matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i'm a Programmer expert and my course is software engineering but for my research i learn math and currently i have this problem with matrices. i search and learn the method of solving this problem but i need a better method.

Comment: @RezaOnline:  how big are the matrices you're dealing with?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom oh i never read it befor, i need to read it and i think it may help me. thanks man.

Comment: @RobertLewis its not static and in my case it isn't bigger than 10 but i think maybe i faced with bigger than 10 x 10 matrix